# What is this blue crystal?

Tags: crystal-structure, identification

I was sorting out some old boxes in one of the rooms in my house, when I found a small container with about 10 grams of this blue crystalline powder. I assume that it contains some form of copper due to the colour, but the label's all ripped and I can't see the name of it.

So what compound is it?

[image: Crystal substance]

It appears to glow in the image, but this is just the reflection from the camera flash and it doesn't look like this in real life.

Comment: Seems like a classic case of $\ce{CuSO4.5H2O}$, you may want to do a Google image search and compare your sample to it (since you have the actual thing you're in a better position to judge whether it looks the same)

Comment: You could try warming it. If it's what @orthocresol says it is, it should turn white when heated (i.e. when it loses water and becomes anhydrous). I did this for my CHEM 101 lab last semester :)

Comment: @Gallifreyan I tried this and it did in fact turn white

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not enough information has been included in the question at the moment to deduce a definitive answer; simply a picture with no other information isn't helpful. I reckon there are a lot of blue-colored crystalline compounds around.

Comment: @M.A.R. What other information do you expect me to provide? An answer has already been given, which I managed to test by heating the compound. And whilst there may be other blue crystalline compounds out there, this one is quite clearly the most common.

Comment: @George FWIW, this already has "too broad" close votes. I agreed with the close votes but didn't want not to leave a comment, closing a well received question.

Comment: Copper(II) nitrate is also a good guess.

Comment: @Zhe Would Copper (II) Nitrate experience the same colour change when heated?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a reference to the color of the anhydrous compound. I do see mentions of it subliming, so that might help you determine which copper(II) salt it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [orthocresol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71769/what-is-this-blue-crystal#comment125636_71769) also mentioned, it's probably [copper sulfate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_sulfate). As you said, the blue color essentially gives it away.

[image]

<sub>(picture taken from [Science Madness Wiki](http://sciencemadness.wikia.com/wiki/Copper(II)_sulfate))</sub>

Answer (score 8):

It's Copper Sulfate, more commonly known as root killer. It's also used in pools to kill algae. In the home, you flush it very slowly down your toilet drain to kill any tree or bush roots growing in the sewage pipes. It's fairly corrosive, so use it sparingly.